# Pandas: How to add a new column combining several Lists from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

i want to combine the content of several columns containing Lists into a new column with just one List.

```
  Name            list0         list1                     list2
0    a  [Now, Now, Now]          None  [works!, works!, works!]
1    b  [Now, Now, Now]  [it, it, it]                      None
2    c  [Now, Now, Now]  [it, it, it]  [works!, works!, works!]
```

the new column should look like this:

```
0              [Now, Now, Now, works!, works!, works!]
1                          [Now, Now, Now, it, it, it]
2    [Now, Now, Now, it, it, it, works!, works!, wo...
```

My solution:

```
#Column of empty lists
new['helper']=np.empty((len(new), 0)).tolist()

#Missing values to empty lists
new['list0']=new['list0'].fillna(new['helper'])
new['list1']=new['list1'].fillna(new['helper'])
new['list2']=new['list2'].fillna(new['helper'])

#Add Lists
new['together']=new['list0']+new['list1']+new['list2']
```

But there must be a faster or at least nicer solution!
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
cols = ['list0','list1','list2']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: [] if x == None else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new['together']=new[['list0', 'list1', 'list2']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

should join them together faster